# After upgrade to ChipMunk 2021.2.1 patch 1 and Gradle 7.2.1 Lost some Android Studio functionality

Tags: android, debugging, upgrade

1. AndroidManifest.xml and all other Layout XML files show me "Class referenced in the manifest, `com....`, was not found in the project or the libraries" errors in all "android:name.
2. When coding in Kotlin activities files (and all other classes as well) the Android Studio don't show any errors/problems (even I do some code errors as test)
3. Try to debug the application and it don't stop at any breakpoints lines.

All Gradle build, install and run my application work well as usual (As worked before that upgrade).

I tried to rebuild, clear Cache, use previous Gradle version and many other suggestions found here, still no success

Comment: I am using Chipmunk 2021.2.1 patch 2 for the flutter app ... and some functionality is missing in it ... Flutter outline all buttons are disabled ... unable to export widget or function ... the suggestion bulb not showing any option ... auto import is not working